# Image not fetching while using Stable diffusion Hugging face model

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-tokenizers, stable-diffusion

```
from auth_token import auth_token
from fastapi import FastAPI,Response ,Request
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import torch
from torch import autocast
from diffusers import StableDiffusionPipeline
from io import BytesIO
import base64


app = FastAPI()

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_credentials= True,
    allow_origins=["*"],
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"]
)


device = "cuda"
model_id = "CompVis/stable-diffusion-v1-4"
pipe = StableDiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained(model_id,revision="fp16",torch_dtype=torch.float16,use_auth_token=auth_token)
print(torch.cuda.get_device_properties(0).total_memory)


@app.get("/")
def generate(prompt : str) :
    with autocast(device):
        pipe.enable_sequential_cpu_offload()
        pipe.enable_attention_slicing(1)

        image = pipe(prompt,guidance_scale=8.5).images[0]

        image.save("testimage.png")

    return {"out":"hello World"}
```

This is the code , where I tried to fetch the image on the basis of provided prompt by the user .

Terminal output :

[Terminal Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQHcB.png)

But when I gave prompt in the browser It didn't generated the image :

Here's the Browser output :

[Browser Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kr6lg.png)

This is the error I got in the browser

Failed to fetch.
Possible Reasons:

CORS

Network Failure

URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

and didn't got any image

Comment: That code only generates and saves the image. You can return it with; `return FileResponse("./testimage.png")`

Comment: But it didn't even saved any generated image .

Comment: Your code works on my machine perfectly fine. Does `curl "http://127.0.0.1:8000/?prompt=banana"` work?